# How to get coloured Output on the Log file in java?

Tags: java, logging, styledtext

I want to write a message in red colour on the log file in java using logger.debug method,is there any way to do it?

Comment: Logs don't support styled text!

Comment: Text is just data, it doesn't have a color.  How are you going to denote color?  Rich text?  HTML?

Comment: You can print it in red in console though: System.err.println()

Comment: i know about the system.err.println(),but to get the output on log file in red colour.

Comment: You are either not listening to, or not understanding, what you are being told.

Comment: Actually i saw some code i.e. using MulticolorLayout to set the colors of messaages in log4j file

Comment: What is `MulticolorLayout`?!?  Links please..  I can only guess that the foftware producing the log is actually writing HTML, as discussed in the answer of feaDawn.  Tip: Add @Lucas (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Answer (score 7):

Logs don't support styled text!  The software used to display them might use some cleverness to color different parts differently, but that is done *purely in the software.*

Answer (score 1):

Logging itself is just plain text with no means of displaying a message in a particular colour (think of it as a txt file). So if you really want colour in your logs you need to encode that as formatting information which can later be interpreted by a text reader, log viewer or web browser.
Probably the easiest would be to use HTML for this. This could for example look like this:

```
<span class="error">02.01.13 14:23 Something bad happend</span>
<span class="info">02.01.13 14:24 This is just an info message</span>
```

and additionally providing a CSS file containing the styling information.

```
.info{ color: #000000; }
.error{ color: #FF0000; font-weight:bold;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a plugin to your IDE if you want colorized logs.